# error with react-navigation when using redux Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-navigation

I implement redux in a react-native app where I use react-navigation.
Before trying to implement redux, react-navigation was working.
My code was:

```
  render(){
      if (this.state.loggedAndVerifiedOrNot) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu');        
      }
      else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
      }
      return(null)
  }
```

In order to integrate redux and the provider, I replaced return(null) part by:

```
      return (
         <Provider store={Store}>
           <App/>
         </Provider>
      )
```

I have **TypeError : undefined is not an object(evaluating ‘this.props.navigation.navigate’)**
I don’t understand where the problem comes from, I didn’t change anything about react-navigation.

Complete code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import Listing from './Listing';
import Menu from './Menu';
import Login from './Login';
import TestRedux from './redux/Components/TestRedux';
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/auth'

firebase.initializeApp({
    XXXXXXXXXXX
});

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user:'',
      loggedAndVerifiedOrNot: false
    }

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user != null) {
            if (user.emailVerified!=null)
            {
              if (user.emailVerified == true)
              this.setState({loggedAndVerifiedOrNot: true})
            }
      }
    });
  }

  render(){
      if (this.state.loggedAndVerifiedOrNot) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Menu');        
      }
      else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
      }
      //return(null)
      return (
           <Provider store={Store}>
             <App/>
           </Provider>
      )
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
      screen: App,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
    Menu: {
      screen: Menu,
    },
    Listing: {
      screen: Listing,
    },
    TestRedux: {
      screen: TestRedux,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: For anyone interested in an up to date solution (as of now) for integrating react-navigation and redux in react native, I posted an answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894358/implement-redux-with-react-navigation-3-in-react-native/55107593#55107593. It might help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First thing i see is you are rendering `<App />` in your App component.
Seems like an issue here

I would also not put this code

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user != null) {
        if (user.emailVerified!=null)
        {
          if (user.emailVerified == true)
          this.setState({loggedAndVerifiedOrNot: true})
        }
  }
});
```

in your constructor but in `ComponentDidMount()` instead

Comment: Louis Lecoq where do you insert the Provider with App with redux ? It is not in your App component ?

Comment: I have an App Component that loads the Redux Provider and a RootStack inside.
My RootStack is a switchNavigator. First screen of my SwitchNavigator is a Component where i check my authentication credentials and navigate to an AuthenticationScreen or MainScreen depending on my credentials validity

Comment: To be sure I understand your answer: you suggest I split my App component : in App component I only render Navigator, and in Navigator component I use react-navigation to go to authentification or Main screen ?

Comment: For anyone interested in an up to date solution (as of now) for integrating react-navigation and redux in react native, I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894358/implement-redux-with-react-navigation-3-in-react-native/55107593#55107593. It might help.

Cheers